# How do I add styles to a component that is passed as prop in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, styles, react-props

I have a component that is passed as a label prop.  I need to add width: 100% for it because otherwise, I cannot use justify-content: space between for my div. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le8ep.png) is how it looks like in developer tools.

```
return (
    <div className={classes.row}>
      <Checkbox
        value={deviceId}
        className={classes.checkbox}
        checked={Boolean(selected)}
        onChange={handleToggle}
        label={
          <div>
            <Tooltip title={t('integrations.deviceEUI')} placement={'top-start'}>
              <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.item}>
                {deviceEui}
              </Typography>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title={t('integrations.deviceName')} placement={'top-start'}>
              <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.item}>
                {name || ''}
              </Typography>
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Simply putting styles inside <div> doesn't help, because everything inside label prop is wrapped in an invisible <span>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the issue, but if you want to simply add styles to a React component, you can simply do the following:

```
cont labelStyle = {
   width: '100%'
};
```

Then inside your return statement, you could attach this `labelStyle` to the parent `<div>` like so:

```
<div style={labelStyle}>
   //other components 
</div>
```

If this isn't what you really mean, then please consider outlining the issue a little more clearly, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In React Native version of this problem, you can simply give the "style" prop to the component as:

```
const NewComponent = ({style}) => {}
```

and now you are able to reach to the "style" prop from another file.

Now, "style" prop is available to use in "NewComponent", write the following code:

```
<NewComponent style={{}}/>
```